# Xcode: Adding WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings to source control

Tags: xcode, version-control

In Xcode, changing settings in File > Workspace Settings... are stored for each Xcode user separately. I want workspace settings to be set the same for all users. My goal it to have the built targets to be copied in the same relative directory.

By default workspace settings are stored in:

> [WorkspaceName].xcworkspace/xcuserdata/[UserName].xcuserdatad

I want the ability make this shared across all users so I can add it to version control.

Comment: I am trying to do this too. What the heck is the point of having a workspace if you can't store workspace-related settings in it?

Answer (score 6):

We ended up writing a small bash script that performed four default write commands to set the correct settings

```
scriptPath="$(dirname "$0")"
cd "$scriptPath"
fullPath=$(pwd)
settingsFile="$fullPath"/<project>.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/$USER.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings

cp -f "$settingsFile" "$settingsFile.plist"

defaults write "$settingsFile" BuildLocationStyle CustomLocation
defaults write "$settingsFile" CustomBuildLocationType RelativeToWorkspace
defaults write "$settingsFile" CustomBuildProductsPath "Build/Products"
defaults write "$settingsFile" CustomBuildIntermediatesPath "Build/Intermediates"

cp -f "$settingsFile.plist" "$settingsFile"
```

Comment: +1, interesting solution. I guess there's no fool-proof way of ensuring this happens whenever someone sets up a new workspace, though?

Comment: I used this idea but would add the following information:
 * I created a new "Aggregate" target with the script as a Build Phase
 * I changed the first line to: 'scriptPath="$PROJECT_FILE_PATH"'
 * I changed the 4. line - remove the brackets from project
 * I changed the last line to: 'cp -f "$settingsFile.plist" "$settingsFile" 2>&1 > /dev/null'

Now a bot can use this for integration as well.